# How to compare versioning numbers python

Tags: python

If i have this

```
a = "4.1.3.79"
b = "4.1.3.64"
```

How can i make this comparison to return **True**?

```
a > b
```

I cant use `float()` or `int()` and python doesn't recognize 4.1.2.79 as a number, How can i do comparison's with these types of values?

I have read up on `StrictVersion` but that only goes up to 3rd version number, and not 4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this will work:

```
a = "4.1.2.79"
b = "4.1.3.64"
#split it
a_list = a.split('.')
b_list = b.split('.')
#to look if a is bigger or not
a_bigger = False
#compare it number by number in list
for i in range(0, len(a_list)):
    #make from both lists one integer
    a_num = int(a_list[i])
    b_num = int(b_list[i])
    #if one num in the a_list is bigger
    if a_num > b_num:
        #make this variable True
        a_bigger = True
        #break the loop so it will show the results
    #else it wil look to the other nums in the lists
#print the result
print('a > b: %s' % str(a_bigger))
```